# Changing Foreground of a TreeViewItem upon selection

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, foreground

In my program I have a `TreeView` in which the user will select different items from. There are a few items in my `TreeView` that are customized upon creation in my c# code-behind.

Like so:

```
public static TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem() //Child Node
{
       Header = new StackPanel //ICON
       {
           Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
           Children =
           {
               new Border {
                   Width = 12,
                   Height = 14,

                   Background = Brushes.Blue,
                   BorderThickness = new Thickness(1.0),
                   BorderBrush = Brushes.Black
              },
              new Label {
                  Content = "Node1"
              }
           }
      }
};
```

I would like these items to display WHITE `foregrounds` when they are selected (just like the default node behavior).

This is what I have tried so far in XAML. It is a style template that I have set for `TreeViewItems`. I receive no compiler errors, but for some reason when I run the program my `TreeView` is not visible.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" >
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False" >
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I fix this so that all of my `TreeView` nodes display white `foregrounds` when selected?

Comment: If I used `TextBlock` would it allow the `Foreground` change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you completely rewrite the template, and you do not write anything instead. Just to set the triggers, not necessarily to do them in the template, you can just set them in `Style`. Template is typically set to change the elements in the visual tree. Try this example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- Set Highlight Background color -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        </Style.Resources>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <!-- Set Foreground color -->
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Root">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Child1" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Child2" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Child3" />
            <TreeViewItem Header="Child4" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

For more information, please see:

[Styling and Templating on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx)

[Example of TreeView Style/Template on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048.aspx)

**`EDIT`**

Try this:

```
public TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem() //Child Node
{
    Header = new StackPanel 
    {
        Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,

        Children =
        {
            new Border 
            {
                Width = 12,
                Height = 14,

                Background = Brushes.Blue,
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(1.0),
                BorderBrush = Brushes.Black
            },

            new Label 
            {
                Content = "Node1",
                Foreground = Brushes.Black,
            }
        }
    }
};

private void AddItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set Selected handler on Selected event
    newItem.Selected += new RoutedEventHandler(newItem_Selected);

    // Set Unselected handler on Unselected event
    newItem.Unselected += new RoutedEventHandler(newItem_Unselected);

    // Add your item
    MyTreeView.Items.Add(newItem);
}

// Set the black color for foreground
private void newItem_Unselected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    TreeViewItem MyTreeViewItem = sender as TreeViewItem;
    StackPanel MyStackPanel = MyTreeViewItem.Header as StackPanel;
    Label MyLabel = MyStackPanel.Children[1] as Label;

    MyLabel.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
}

// Set the white color for foreground
private void newItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem MyTreeViewItem = sender as TreeViewItem;
    StackPanel MyStackPanel = MyTreeViewItem.Header as StackPanel;
    Label MyLabel = MyStackPanel.Children[1] as Label;

    MyLabel.Foreground = Brushes.White;         
}
```

`Note:` This code can be shortened and made easier if you use a template for `TreeViewItem`.

Comment: This is working for all of the normal `TreeViewItems`, but the ones I mentioned in my question are not being affected (The custom ones).

Comment: @Ericafterdark, I don't see a need for `Label` in your code. Unless you really need it replace it with `TextBlock` and original, simpler solution with `Style` should work straight away for your items

Comment: @Anatoliy Nikolaev, this answer seems like it would work if I was adding nodes with a button click. But at the moment my Selected Nodes are controlled by a `SelectedItemChanged` method. How would I call to those event handlers from a `SelectedItemChanged` method? @dkozl - Changed it to `TextBlock`.

Comment: @Eric after dark: Just add two events to your `newItem`, like this: `newItem.Selected += new RoutedEventHandler(newItem_Selected);`, e.g. before the addition of TreeView.Items. You do it somehow you add?