# How to change color childs of only selected item in TreeView

Tags: c#, xaml, avalonia

How to change color childs of only selected item in TreeView?
My style:

```
<Style Selector="TreeViewItem:selected TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style>
```

But this works for all child TreeViewItem in node.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08ecE.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are brushes that used by default Template for TreeView.

`HighlightTextBrushKey` - You can use for foreground.

`HighlightBrushKey` - You can use for background.

You can do to change foreground:

```
<TreeView.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush Color="White" x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"/>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: I just want to rewrite the style with my style. But the problem is that subsidiaries are painted. Or I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: Could you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320842/changing-foreground-of-a-treeviewitem-upon-selection)

Comment: My mistake was using a selector on all child elements instead of a direct child selector (>).